# Нужны ли знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли знаки препинания во втором предложении? На всякий случай цитирую в контексте, поскольку предложение получается двусоставное(?). 
"Поначалу они каждый день ходили-жаловались Большому Боссу, что у них не хватает данных для работы. Подбивали молодёжь в машинном отделении(, или - ) остановить вращение хоть на пять минут!"

(Вдруг стало стыдно, что давнишний рассказ "Кольцо обратного действия" до сих пор висит необработанный :( Читать невозможно! Так что, прошу прощения, что буду приставать ко всем, как банный лист к ж...железной шайке.)

Answer (score 1):

> Нужны ли знаки препинания во втором предложении?

**Не нужны** (нет оснований для их постановки).

Правильно:

***Подбивали*** молодёжь в машинном отделении **остановить** вращение...

Ср.:

*И еще Зойка **подбивала** Веру **спросить** у Лидии Александровны, можно ли взять пустые бутылки из-под вина…* (Ю. Трифонов "Вера и Зойка").

Comment: Спасибо. Изначально (при автоматическом написании) никакого знака у меня не стояло. Сомнения появились, когда начал задумываться. Вот как вредно думать! :)

Answer (score 0):

***Подбивали молодёжь в машинном отделении остановить вращение хоть на пять минут.***

Подбивали (на что?) *остановить*. *Остановить* - дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом.  Ср.: *просили (о чём?) подождать*.  Знаки не нужны.